# Dart, polymer - how to dynamically create a context sensitive dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, dart, dart-polymer

I'm using Dart and paper elements. I am displaying a table, and depending on the cell I click, I want a dropdown menu. The location of the menu should be next/on/near to the cell I click. The menus will contain items which are unknown at design time, dependent on the cell clicked, and dependent on user data. I think it's impossible to create a <'template> for this in the HTML file, so I will need to build the menu totally dynamically (I think...?).

So, I'd like some advice on the approach please, because I am hacking at the moment: not the best approach.

Here is my initial idea, which could be completely bad!

```dart
void makePopup(TableCellElement cell){
PaperDropdownMenu ddMenu= new PaperDropdownMenu();
List<String> allItems=getItems();
for (String item in allItems){
    PaperItem pitem=new PaperItem();
    pitem.innerHtml=item;
    ddMenu.children.add(pitem);
 }
 cell.children.add(ddMenu);//??
}
```

Should I add the menu as a child to the cell (doesn't seem good - the behaviour is not great - from what I've tried). Or should I add it high up the node tree? (But then the location of the menu will be tricky.) Do I need to add core-menu? I also tried PaperMenuButton - but this doesn't allow children, and cannot be added as a child to the cell.

Thanks,Steve

Answer (score 2):

You could use a common parent Poylmer element which holds the data and has your cells and the dropdown as children (or grandchildren).
Then you update the data in the common parent element when another cell is activated. The dropdown just binds to this data in the parent element and updates itself depending on the data.
You can use absolute positioning to place the dropdown near or over the active cell.

Comment: Hi @gunter. Many thanks, Yes, I eventually reached that method! (I'm glad...). But, after I build the menu on a click of the cell, I cannot expose the menu - I have tried: paperMenuButton.click() but nothing happens. I have to click a second time to expand the menu, which is not a good user interface. How do I do that? Cheers, S

Comment: Hi, found it.    paperMenuButtonDSD.opened=true;   
cheers, S